# Change flash src with jquery?

Tags: jquery, flash

Hi I have a flash menu showing a few links, but when the user is logged in I want to change the menu from menu1 to menu2 ... so that it will display "My Account" rather than "Signup"

The code below is for my flash:

```
<div id="menu"> 
 <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="825" height="69" id="menu1" align="middle">
 <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
 <param name="movie" value="menu1.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> <embed src="menu1.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="825" height="69" name="menu1" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
 </object>
 </div>
```

Php:

```
if (loggedin())
 {

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
   CHANGE FLASH LINK HERE
   </script>';  


 }
```

Could this be done without having to write all the above code out again?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu > object > embed").attr("src", "new link");
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was easy ! :D
Apparently I have to wait 6mins to accept this as answer..haha

Answer (score 0):

If `loggedin()` is a load-time check done on the server-side, why not simply change the output from PHP?

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <?php if (loggedin()) { ?>
        <object ...> ...
            <param name="movie" value="menu2.swf" /> ...
        </object>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <object ...> ...
            <param name="movie" value="menu1.swf" /> ...
        </object>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

If you really must do it from script then yes, you should create a new Flash object (by `innerHTML` or DOM methods, or getting a script like SWFObject to do it for you). Changing the source of a plugin object is not something you can do reliably cross-browser (especially IE).

It might be better to include both menus on the page and just use `display` to hide one of them.

It would almost certainly be better not to use Flash menus, which tend to be a usability, accessibility and SEO disaster. You've got a lot of animation possibilities built into jQuery and HTML5/CSS3/etc is increasingly capable of pretty effects. Flash menus are *so* 2003.