# Changing a Flash Video with Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, flash, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change flash src with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830944/change-flash-src-with-jquery)

**EDIT** *I figured out the first issue (not loading at all) so I took that portion out*

I have a flashplayer that I make like so:

```
<div id="video_content"><div id="flash_wrapper">
                <object classid="MyID" width="402" height="285" id="videoplayer" align="middle">
                    <param name="movie" value="videoplayer.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                    <param name="FlashVars" value="screencast_url=myVideo.flv" id="flash" />
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="videoplayer.swf" width="402" height="285">
                        <param name="movie" value="videoplayer.swf" />
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                        <param name="play" value="true" />
                        <param name="loop" value="true" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                        <param name="menu" value="true" />
                        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                        <param name="salign" value="" />
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param name="FlashVars" value="screencast_url=myVideo.flv" id="flash" />

                    <!--<![endif]-->
                        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                        </a>
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    </object>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                </object>
            </div>
```

I have buttons that I want to use to change the video playing. The js method to change videos looks like this:

```
function ChangeVideo(videoIndex) {

//Video Location String
var vidLocation = "screencast_url=";

//Determines what video to load
switch (videoIndex) {
    case 1:
        //Change Video Location
        vidLocation += "myVideo.flv";
        break;
    case 2:
        //Change Video Location
        vidLocation += "myVideo2.flv";
        break;
    case 3:
        //Change Video Location
        vidLocation += "myVideo3.flv";
        break;
    case 4:
        //Change Video Location
        vidLocation += "myVideo4.flv";
        break;
}

//Change value of flashplayer FlashVar
$('#flash').val(vidLocation);
}
```

The video looks to have loaded correctly and all the information seems to be correct, but the video will not play when I hit the play button (Current video keeps playing).

How would you load another video into a flash player after it has been loaded?

**EDIT2** If I try this:

```
//Creates empty values
var flashvars = vidLocation;
var params = {};
var attributes = {};

//Change video
swfobject.embedSWF("videoplayer.swf", "video_content", "300", "120", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Instead of :

```
//Change value of flashplayer FlashVar
$('#flash').val(vidLocation);
```

Which seems to reload the player now, but it still does not play.

Comment: One issue I see is you have "flash" defined as the ID of more than one node. Not sure if that's the cause of the problem, but might be worth looking into. Also might want to try $('#flash').attr('value', vidLocation); and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I tried that to and it didn't work. I think I need to do some more reading on loading new videos in flash before I can get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlashVars are only loaded when the movie initially loads, so you can't update the video url just by updating the DOM attributes.  I recommend using [swfObject's "dynamic" loading method](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to load the new videos via javascript.

Comment: It took a while, but I eventually got the video playing

Comment: @Angelo - That's basically what swfobject handles for you.  It will load a new `object`, or I believe replace an existing one if you call it on the same container.

Comment: @SsRide360 - Sorry for the lack of detail, but glad to have helped.